# Компиляция проекта под Linux Ubuntu. Ошибка "undefined reference to".

Tags: gcc, c, c++, linux

Вечер добрый!
В общем опишу ситуацию: Есть набор файлов *.c и* .h. Есть скрипт makefile. Однако при попытке выполнить "make", в терминале появляется следующий список сообщений:

> `jack@jack:~/debug_tools$ make
> cc -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall -MD -MP -MF .dep/ui.o.d   -c -o ui.o ui.c
> cc -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall -MD -MP -MF .dep/protocol.o.d   -c -o protocol.o protocol.c
> cc -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall -MD -MP -MF .dep/graph.o.d   -c -o graph.o graph.c
> cc -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall -MD -MP -MF .dep/gps.o.d   -c -o gps.o gps.c
> cc -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall -MD -MP -MF .dep/ui.d  ui.o fix.o protocol.o graph.o gps.o gnuplot_i.o   -o ui
> graph.o: In function 'graph_draw':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:53: undefined reference to 'XSetForeground'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:56: undefined reference to 'XDrawLine'
> graph.o: In function 'path_draw_point':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:90: undefined reference to 'cos'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:91: undefined reference to 'sin'
> graph.o: In function 'ui_func':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:242: undefined reference to 'XFlush'
> graph.o: In function 'process_events':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:256: undefined reference to 'XPending'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:258: undefined reference to 'XNextEvent'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:261: undefined reference to 'XKeycodeToKeysym'
> graph.o: In function 'ui_init':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:383: undefined reference to 'XOpenDisplay'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:384: undefined reference to 'XDisplayName'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:391: undefined reference to 'XCreateSimpleWindow'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:395: undefined reference to 'XSetStandardProperties'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:397: undefined reference to 'XCreateGC'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:398: undefined reference to 'XSetBackground'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:399: undefined reference to 'XSetForeground'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:401: undefined reference to 'XSelectInput'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:403: undefined reference to 'XMapRaised'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:405: undefined reference to 'XClearWindow'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:406: undefined reference to 'XSync'
> graph.o: In function 'showtext':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:445: undefined reference to 'XSetForeground'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:450: undefined reference to 'XDrawImageString'
> graph.o: In function 'clear_wnd':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:454: undefined reference to 'XSetForeground'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:455: undefined reference to 'XFillRectangle'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:456: undefined reference to 'XSetForeground'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:458: undefined reference to 'XDrawLine'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:463: undefined reference to 'XDrawLine'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:468: undefined reference to 'XDrawLine'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:472: undefined reference to 'XDrawLine'
> graph.o: In function 'setstat':
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:480: undefined reference to 'XSetForeground'
> /home/jack/debug_tools/graph.c:481: undefined reference to 'XFillRectangle'
> collect2: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
> make: *** [ui] Ошибка 1
> jack@jack:~/debug_tools$`

Дело в том, что с программированием под Linux не сталкивался раньше. Все сырцы писались другим человеком, который пропал бесследно. В итоге я застрял на этих вот ошибках. 
Вопрос: в какую сторону копать и что с ними делать (имею ввиду "undefined reference to")?

**Добавлено из комментария**.

Вот содержание makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall    
LDFLAGS = ${CFLAGS}

all: ui calib_edit uart_9bit    
ui: ui.o fix.o protocol.o graph.o gps.o gnuplot_i.o    
calib_edit: calib_edit.o protocol.o    
uart_9bit: uart_9bit.o

DEPDIR = .dep    
CFLAGS += -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$(@F).d

-include $(shell mkdir .dep 2>/dev/null) $(wildcard .dep/*)

.PHONY: clean

clean:    
    rm -f *.o    
    rm -rf .dep    
    rm -f ui calib_edit uart_9bit
```

`uart_9bit` и `calib_edit` собираются без проблем, а вот ui никак. `make clean` ничего не дает.

Comment: попробуйте скомпилировать самостоятельно

Comment: спасибо за совет. но, увы, не помогло. тот же эффект.

Comment: Странно. Ключики -lX11 -lm стоят, а функции из них (в основном X11, но sin/cos -- libm) не подключаются. Вы начинает с `make clean` (если, конечно, такая есть в вашем Makefile)?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

еще из общих приемов: попробуйте добавить опцию -v к CFLAGS; тогда gcc напишет список директорий для поиска инклудов и библиотек. Возможно, стоит пройтись по этим директориям, посмотреть, что там лежит

Comment: спасибо за совет. попробую)

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте в файле graph.c, включены ли хедеры math.h и Xlib.h

Comment: math.h включен в файле graph.c, а Xlib.h в файле graph.h

Comment: А хедеры-то причём? Ругается ld, причём на имена, которые в X11. @Johnny_Stray пакет libx11-dev, разумеется, установлен?

Comment: libx11-dev установлен.
пока пытался побороть ошибки, вообще все, что можно было поставил.

Comment: Если бы ругался линкер, там другие бы слова стояли. И ругается еще и по поводу -lm. Уж она-то должна стоять

Comment: На самом деле, ничего не понимаю. Надо бы весь текст посмотреть, но он здоровый очень. Если бы где-нибудь его выложили, чтобы скачать.

Comment: могу выложить исходники архивом. сейчас дам ссылку.

Comment: ОК. Давай.

Comment: http://deadscorp.ifolder.ru/28363184

Comment: Из приёмов шаманства: добавить в команду `gcc -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall -MD -MP -MF .dep/ui.d  ui.o fix.o protocol.o graph.o gps.o gnuplot_i.o   -o u` в хвост `-lX11 -m` (второй раз) и посмотреть, что-нибудь изменится? (ошибки это не устранит, но вдруг картинка будет другая)

Comment: Хорошая идея. Мне вообще не понравилось, что -l не в конце. Хотел проверить у себя, а наткнулся на вообще неожиданный результат:

sin() **без -lm собирается** (и считает). Ubuntu 10.04, gcc --version

    gcc.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

Почему так ?

Comment: Собирается. Кроме двух предупреждений при компиляции calib_edit.c никаких жалоб. Ошибки: не используется константа SENSOR_US и нет возвращаемого значения для не-void функции.

Comment: попробовал выполнить "gcc -fshort-enums -Wno-unused-result -lX11 -lm -pthread -ggdb -O0 -Wall -MD -MP -MF .dep/ui.d  ui.o fix.o protocol.o graph.o gps.o gnuplot_i.o   -o ui -lX11 -m", заругался только на sin и cos. 
потом в конце, поменял -m на -lm, собралось, но при запуске получившегося файла, в итоге выдает ошибку сегментирования и умирает. но уже что-то. спасибо) можно еще как-то попробовать собрать, чтобы заставить таки конечный файл работать?

и еще вопрос: в чем трюк с перенесением двух ключей в конец?

Comment: Бред. У меня собирается с libm.so (libm-2.11.1.so) и libX11.so. Попробуйте заменить -lX11 -m на -l:libX11.so -l:libm.so. У меня результат получается одинаковый. На порту естественно ничего нет, но ./ui --help какое-то окошко выводит :) Ну и locate libX11.so. Боюсь, что что-то в системе наворочено установками, вот и путается ld.

Comment: да, результат тотже. окошко, по идее, как раз то, что нужно. но у меня оно в итоге закрывается с сообщением в терминале "ошибка сегментирования". но первую часть функций она выполняет, т.е. опрашивает устройства и находит. потом устанавливает режим его работы в один из имеющихся, а после уже вываливается в ошибку. не могу понять причины.
кстати, а в чем таки трюк с перестановкой ключей в конец?
на самом деле, из всей этой программы, мне нужна только одна ее функция. она может получить изображение с матрицы устройства и вывести на экран. но где оно в коде и как это переложить на винды,не знаю.

Comment: Да, не знал, что имеет значение, куда вставить в команде компиляции имена разделяемых библиотек. Знал такое про статические библиотеки. Спасибо всем за урок.

Comment: Спасибо всем вам за помощь!) Очень много времени убил на борьбу с проблемой (около недели), и без вас бы не справился. Теперь буду копать в сторону способа обхода ошибки сегментирования. Не очень понятно, отчего она появляется, но, думаю, могу попытаться обойти. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: С достаточно высокой вероятностью можно предположить, что это следствие каши из библиотек. Смотреть надо после того, как будет нормально собираться по первоначальному Makefile. (Ну а то, что gdb может работать с посмертным дампом, Вы в курсе)

Comment: По первоначальному, боюсь, собираться не будет.

Comment: У меня собирается. "Она же не подходит -- У меня подошла -- А как? -- А кувалдочкой". Только вот работать после кувалдочки не обязано.

Comment: Ну, у меня собралась вроде. Только, да, не работает, как должна. Но, надеюсь, это у меня обойти уже получится. Очень на это надеюсь.